# How to remove item collection using current context JPA, JSF, Java Collections

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, collections

I want to remove comment that do not match the current movie;

info

```
         jpaController = (CommentFacade) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "commentJpa");
         movieController = (MovieController) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{movie}", MovieController.class);
         private List<Comment> userCommentItems = null;
         private Comment userComment = null;

 public List<Comment> getUserCommentItems() {
    if (userCommentItems == null) {
        getUserPagingInfo();
        Vector comments = (Vector) jpaController.findAll();
        Vector v = new Vector(comments);
        for (Iterator iterator = comments.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                userComments = (Comment) iterator.next();
                if (userComments.getMovie().getIdMovie() != movieController.getMovie().getIdMovie()){
                    v.remove(userComments);
                }
            }
        userCommntItems = v;
    }
    return userCommentItems ;
}


  <h:panelGroup>
       <h:outputText value="Item #{comment.userPagingInfo.firstItem +  1}..#{comment.userPagingInfo.lastItem} of #{comment.userPagingInfo.itemCount}"/>&nbsp;
      <h:commandLink action="#{comment.userPrev}" value="Previous #{comment.userPagingInfo.batchSize}" 
    rendered="#{comment.userPagingInfo.firstItem >= comment.userPagingInfo.batchSize}"/>
     <h:commandLink action="#{comment.userNext}" value="Next #{comment.userPagingInfo.batchSize}" rendered="#{comment.userPagingInfo.lastItem +  comment.userPagingInfo.batchSize <= comment.userPagingInfo.itemCount}"/>&nbsp;
     <h:commandLink action="#{comment.userNext}" value="Remaining #{comment.userPagingInfo.itemCount - comment.userPagingInfo.lastItem}"
                          rendered="#{comment.userPagingInfo.lastItem < comment.userPagingInfo.itemCount && comment.userPagingInfo.lastItem + comment.userPagingInfo.batchSize > comment.userPagingInfo.itemCount}"/>

    <h:dataTable value="#{comment.userCommentItems}" var="item"
             border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px"
             rendered="#{not empty comment.movieController.movie.commentCollection}">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="IdUser"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.idUser.user}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Text"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.text}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: no error but null I get an empty datatable

Comment: No sorry I'm getting all comments now, all comments for all movies. I mean once comments are up they stay the same for all movies I navigate to.

Comment: What does a call to getIdMovie() return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is awful code. How about this version?

```
public List<Comment> getUserCommentItems() {
    if (userCommentItems == null) {
        getUserPagingInfo();
        List<Comment> comments = jpaController.findAll();
        for (Iterator<Comment> iterator = comments.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                userComments = iterator.next();
                if (!userComments.getMovie().equals(movieController.getMovie()){
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        userCommntItems = comments;
    }
    return userCommentItems ;
}
```

**Improvements:**

- No more usage of deprecated Vector class (especially no more unnecessary casts)
- Compare object using `equals()`, not `==` (you should implement `Movie.equals(Object)` accordingly).
- No need to copy the collection, work on the original (if your DAO returns something I can't change then it sucks)

---

But to actually solve your problem:

Are you reusing this component for different movies? If so, keeping the comments in a field is nonsense. Remove all assignments to  and reads from `userCommentItems`.

Comment: metod remove in class java.util.iterator <E> cannot be apply to given types required: no arguments found: myBeans

Comment: @Ignacio sorry, my bad, it takes no parameters. It removes the current element in the iteration (fixed code now)

Comment: this are the only assignments to and reads from userCommentItems

Comment: @Ignacio you are not showing any code that writes data to a database, you are just filtering data. We have no way of knowing how stuff ends up in your database given the code you have shown

Comment: It does not write data on a database but to a screen, using getter and setter for userCommentItems.

Comment: ah, I see, you mean HTML tables.

Comment: It the same the first movie comes with the correct comments but all of the others come with those first comments.

Comment: @Ignacio yes, see my last paragraph

Comment: Yesss fixed just needed to reset userCommnets to null! Thank you very much!!!! best regards